# jQuery .wrap .unwrap responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery

Forgive me, I am fairly new to javascript. I am trying to remove a div's parent below 980px wide and then add it back in above 980px. I am using the following code that I have put together from looking at other jQuery.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    var Tags = jQuery( ".case-studies .items-row div.span4" );
    var wi = jQuery(window).width();
    if (wi < 980) {
       if ( Tags.parent().is( "div.items-row.cols-3.row-0.row-fluid" ) ) {
    Tags.unwrap();
       }
    } else {
         (Tags.wrap.parent( "<div .items-row.cols-3.row-0.row-fluid></div>" ));}

});
```

I'm guessing you will realise I am experiencing a few issues!

- The jQuery doesn't apply below 980px on page load, however when you start with a large screen size and shrink the width below 980px the jQuery works.
- Once the jQuery has fired and the screen size goes above 980px, the div that has been removed does not get reapplied.

Please explain where I have gone wrong as I would like to learn.

Thanks for your time

**UPDATE**
The html before any jQuery is:

```
<section>
  <div class="items-row cols-3 row-1 row-fluid">
        <div class="span4"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

With the following jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    var Tags = jQuery( ".case-studies .items-row div.span4" );
    var wi = jQuery(window).width();

    if (wi < 980) {
       if ( Tags.parent().is( "div.items-row.cols-3.row-0.row-fluid" ) ) {
    Tags.unwrap();
       }
    } 

    else {

    Tags.wrap( "<div></div>");


         }
});
```

This now occurs above 980px on page load:

```
<section>
  <div class="items-row cols-3 row-1 row-fluid">
        <div>
            <div class="span4"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And when i refresh the page below 980px:

```
<section>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</section>
```

The result below 980px is correct, however only runs when i refresh the screen. The result above 980px is not my intended result, i would like it to remain or return to:

```
<section>
      <div class="items-row cols-3 row-1 row-fluid">
            <div class="span4"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What is this part, `Tags.wrap.parent( "<div .items-row.cols-3.row-0.row-fluid></div>" )`, *meant* to be doing? `wrap()` is a method, which requires an argument to do anything, parent takes a selector not an HTML string, and the supplied string isn't valid HTML and nor will it create valid HTML. Did you, at any point, look at your browser's JavaScript console (`F12` in most browsers) and see any reported errors?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as i said i am new to javascript, you will notice below that Tdelang has already pointed that out and I have changed it.

Comment: And it remains broken. Can you show the (relevant) HTML you want for the view above 980px and the (relevant) HTML you want below 980px? Because without that we're trying to guess what you want to do from looking at non-working code.

Comment: I have updated the original post, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`#1`: Call the function once on page load, that way you don't need to resize to get it

`#2`:

```
else {
     (Tags.wrap.parent( "<div .items-row.cols-3.row-0.row-fluid></div>" ));}
```

should be

```
else {
     (Tags.wrap( "<div .items-row.cols-3.row-0.row-fluid></div>" ));}
```

Comment: ok i changed to:
jQuery(window).load(function () {

now it only works under 980px with a page reload

#2 The else runs above 980px when the page loads so i get an extra div parent added when i don't want it